# How to include packages when creating executable with Pyinstaller

Tags: pandas, pip, pyinstaller, python-packaging

I'm trying to create a .exe with some packages I need to include in order to make my code work. But I'm getting errors regarding the importing packages.

```
hiddenimports=['pandas', 'sys', 'os', 'tkinter', 'requests', 'openpyxl']
```

I included those packages and I executed this on my venv:

```
pyinstaller --noconsole --name="Display Catalog" --icon="icone.ico" --add-data="icone.ico;." --hidden-import pandas --hidden-import sys --hidden-import os --hidden-import tkinter --hidden-import requests --hidden-import openpyxl --onefile main.py
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to include those packages within my .exe ?
How can I keep it "light" as this .exe will be shared with other people who don't have python and those dependencies installed ?

Comment: I tried editing the .spec manually but didn't work.

Comment: Hi, could you show the content of your spec file? Also, what happens if you try to build without specifying hidden imports?